# jQuery .css() fallbacks?

Tags: jquery, css, fallback

What is the proper way to do fallbacks with .css()? This would most commonly be used for font fallbacks but I am using it for cursor images.

Here's what I got that isn't working:

```
$("#dragable").css('cursor','url(images/grabbing.gif), -moz-grabbing, auto');
```

**UPDATE: can someone tell me the valid CSS for starters?

What I have:

```
cursor: url(images/grabbing.gif), -moz-grabbing, auto;
```

... doesn't work.**

Comment: For font fallbacks you should use the standard CSS syntax, eg `jQueryObj.css({ fontFamily: '"Primary Font", "Fallback Font", serif' });`. Other properties will be another matter and I'll leave that up to the hopefully forthcoming answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using dynamic inline styles not always a good idea. Consider dynamic classes. Define somewhere in css specific class for draggable element:

```
.cur-draggable { cursor: url(images/grabbing.gif), -moz-grabbing, auto; }
```

And try to add this class, instead of style itself;

```
$("#dragable").addClass('cur-draggable');
```

Comment: ... this makes life easier. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that breaks it, but the values aren't being written to the DOM.

Though, the css() function is really just a shortcut to editing the "style" attribute inline on the element, so you could do this to get the same result:

```
$("#dragable").attr('style','cursor: url(images/grabbing.gif), -moz-grabbing, auto');
```

Comment: Note that this will overwrite other style properties.

Comment: True, but you could easily bypass that by first retrieving the contents of the style attribute and then appending the string. Something like $("#dragable").attr('style',$(this).attr('style') + 'cursor: url(images/grabbing.gif), -moz-grabbing, auto');  -- not sure that exact syntax will work, but the principle is there.